# Loading JSON file for reading and selecting data

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that I load into python. I want to take a keyword from the file (which is very big), like country rank or review from info taken from the internet. I tried

```
json.load('filename.json')
```

but I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, how do I select part of a json file if it is very big?

Comment: Did you try `json.loads('filename.json')` ? You're reading a string

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to open the file then pass that to json load like this

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('filename.json') as data:    
    output = json.load(data)

pprint(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import json

json_data_file = open("json_file_path", 'r').read() # r for reading the file
json_data = json.loads(json_data_file)
```

Access the data using the keys as follows :

```
json_data['key']
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.load()` expects the file handle after it has been opened:

```
with open('filename.json') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)
```

For example if your json data looked like this:

```
{
"maps": [
    {
        "id": "blabla",
        "iscategorical": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "blabla",
        "iscategorical": "0"
    }
],
"masks": {
    "id": "valore"
},
"om_points": "value",
"parameters": {
    "id": "valore"
}
}
```

To access parts of the data, use:

```
data["maps"][0]["id"]
data["masks"]["id"]
data["om_points"]
```

That code can be found in this SO answer: 
[Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python)

Comment: I get      "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' "   when I use this code, i like however the way it is done

Comment: ok now error say:              " raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s,  err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value"

Comment: and then I try using json.loads() and get " TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper' "

Comment: Are you sure your file filename.json contains data in it?